# How to configure Cloudfront to vary on request protocol

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

My custom origin returns a response that can vary on the request's protocol.  The site needs some urls to be available over http, so I cannot just disable http in Cloudfront.

However, Cloudfront is caching the http response and serving it for requests made via https.

I am confused by this behavior because http://example.com is a different resource than https://example.com - so they should not be served the same cached response.  However, Cloudfront seems to do this.

Is there a way to instruct Cloudfront to use the request protocol in its cache key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the request protocol is not currently supported in the cache key. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/controlling-the-cache-key.html#cache-key-understand-cache-policy

Comment: I read the limitations of the cache policy before posting =(  Surely there is a way to accomplish this?  A way to tag origins based on protocol.  Or any other feasible way?

Answer (score 0):

This is (or became?) possible by adding the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header to the Cache Key. This is a header that CloudFront injects into the request based on the inbound protocol used (HTTP or HTTPS)